# Advanced Wordpress php Help

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to include this [sliding out info panel](http://elitedesignstudios.com/wp-content/themes/auzora/slideout.php)
 that i created into [my wordpress site](http://www.elitedesignstudios.com). I have tried using    in the page.php file and the index.php file and have had no success. My site is a single page site and i believe i am having issues figuring this out because of that. The include file is actually a whole html page so im getting stumped on how to go about this. Please Help......Sugestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the whole html page. You just need this part (the button and the div). Put it in the page.php somewhere in the body tag, doesn't really matter where since it's positioned in the css:

```
<div class="panel"> 
    <h3>Email Subscription</h3> 
    <p>Enter your email address below to receive promotional products and exclussive Elite givaways!</p> 

  <p><input name="" type="text" value="enter your email" /><input name="" type="submit" /></p> 
</div> 
<a class="trigger" href="#">infos</a>
```

Then make sure you have this javacript in the head tag in header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Then also obviously need the jquery js in the head tag in header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

And the css for the trigger and box in the head tag in header.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Se my answer, I edited it saying in which files in the theme.

Comment: thank you...ill give it a try and see if i run into any issues

Comment: Im running into a issue with the css....how does the trigger and box find the css file...i don't get how putting the link in the header.php file connects it to the div's in the page.php that i added

Comment: *update* i am getting it to work somewhat by putting the css in the main css file but please visit my site and see what is happening

Comment: sorry to do this but i am having progress and want to update my status.....i got everything to work but my issue now is that the css has it to float right but my content area is only 960px....how do i get it to float on the right side of the browser window

Comment: To position it 100 pixels from the top and 0 pixels från the right in the browser: { position:fixed; top:100px; right:0px; }. This will make the div sit there even if you scroll.